# Vagrant up not working, possibly SSH connection issue

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I've setup my VirtualBox and Vagrant for the first time like so:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
sudo apt-get install vagrant
vagrant box add ubuntu/trusty64 https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/trusty/current/trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box
```

.. this installed Vagrant 1.4.3 and Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager 4.3.10_Ubuntu. Also, I have Ubuntu 14.04.

Then to fire it up (and figure out what's up):

```
VAGRANT_LOG=info vagrant up
```

.. which gets as far as here:

```
[default] Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
```

..then it just repeats the following process over and over. I can see it's an issue with SSH, but I don't know why.

```
INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["/usr/bin/VBoxManage", "showvminfo", "7ab49709-85ee-4bf0-b4bd-7bc200ae87de", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["/usr/bin/VBoxManage", "showvminfo", "7ab49709-85ee-4bf0-b4bd-7bc200ae87de", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO ssh: Attempting SSH connnection...
 INFO ssh: Attempting to connect to SSH...
 INFO ssh:   - Host: 127.0.0.1
 INFO ssh:   - Port: 2222
 INFO ssh:   - Username: vagrant
 INFO ssh:   - Key Path: ["/home/martyn/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"]
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["/usr/bin/VBoxManage", "showvminfo", "7ab49709-85ee-4bf0-b4bd-7bc200ae87de", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["/usr/bin/VBoxManage", "showvminfo", "7ab49709-85ee-4bf0-b4bd-7bc200ae87de", "--machinereadable"]
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["/usr/bin/VBoxManage", "showvminfo", "7ab49709-85ee-4bf0-b4bd-7bc200ae87de", "--machinereadable"]
```

If I try just running the `vagrant ssh` command alone (in another CLI tab, as this process is still running) it just hangs

Answer (score 0):

Do you have *private_key* in your .vagrant folder?
If you try to [destroy](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/destroy.html) the whole thing and add the box again. Do you get the same message?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I haven't put any keys in my .vagrant folder. I just followed the getting started guide in the docs, it didn't insist I had to create keys. Would that help here? Anyway I did have initial problems setting up the box. I was wondering if maybe when I added the box intially I had attempted to 'vagrant up' and had a session running when I added the box before, maybe. I tried destroying anyway, and adding again as you instructed but it just tells me "The box you're attempting to add already exists". And, `vagrant up` just gives me the same issue as before.